# Container got killed Running out of Physical memory.

Tags: shell, hive, sqoop

containerID=container_e73_1498567983552_26942_01_000069] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_e73_1498567983552_26942_01_000069 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 29404 29401 29404 29404 (bash) 1 2 108654592 305 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx900m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/usercache

Comment: How do I change the Limitation of memory using a command rather than making changes on the cluster directly

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in sqoop import command:

`-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=12288 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx9830m`

Example:

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=12288 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx9830m \
other generic args like connection string etc
```

Calculate the memory requirement based on size of data.